# Why isn't the compiler warns about casting to enum?

Tags: types, enums, casting, d

I was quite shocked, when I realised that D allows the user to cast a compatible value to an `enum` and therefore make it possible to produce an invalid `enum` value, which I think is problematic in many levels.

So for example, if I create a library, where I expose an `enum` type and a function that is working on it:

```d
module greek;

import std.stdio : writeln;

enum GreekLetters
{
    ALPHA,
    BETA,
}


void writeGreekLetter(GreekLetters letter)
{
    final switch(letter)
    {
        case GreekLetters.ALPHA:
            writeln("\u03B1");
            break;

        case GreekLetters.BETA:
            writeln("\u03B2");
            break;
    }
}
```

... and then the user does the following:

```d
import greek : GreekLetters, writeGreekLetter;

void main()
{
    writeGreekLetter(cast(GreekLetters)2);
}
```

... the compiler will not complain, but obviously the program will crash with a (not so nice) exception:

```
core.exception.SwitchError@greek(14): No appropriate switch clause found
```

So my questions are:

1. Does this mean, that me, the library designer who tries to make things safe (that is, handled), should avoid using the `final switch`, and use other approaches (maybe a regular `switch` with a `default` case) and handle the invalid `enum` state there (returning an error, or throwing an exception)?
2. Why does a modern and safe language like D allows me to do such a thing? That is, what is the main reason casting to `enum` is allowed in the first place? (From the language design point of view.)

> **Note:** I'm aware, that `enum` can have a basetype, which can be string and in that case `writeGreekLetter` doesn't really needed, however this is just a dummy example to demonstrate my main concern/problem.

Comment: Probably because casts are explicit. The Enum protects you from stupid mistakes, but still allows you to get around it if you *really* want to. There may be a legitimate use case.

Comment: @Carcigenicate and can you think of any?

Comment: I don't actually know D, but there may be some case where you want to calculate some int value, then cast it to its corresponding Enum value. The Enum value would then be dependant on whatever went into the calculation.

Comment: @Carcigenicate in that case, use a switch (or if, whatever) on the `int` value, and choose the proper `enum` based on the value. What I'm trying to say is: there are safer alternatives!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In D, casts are a blunt low-level operation: by using them, the programmer acknowledges that they are avoiding type system restrictions intentionally. (This is why the casting syntax uses the special `cast` keyword - aid code review by providing something greppable).

To "safely" convert an integer to an integral enum, you can use [`std.conv.to`](https://dlang.org/library/std/conv/to.html). For example:

```
writeGreekLetter(2.to!GreekLetters);
```

This code will still compile, but will provide a better error message at runtime:

```
Value (2) does not match any member value of enum 'GreekLetters'
```

To check the conversion of an integer literal at compile-time, you can use CTFE to assign it to a [manifest constant](https://dlang.org/spec/enum.html#manifest_constants) first:

```
enum greekLetter2 = 2.to!GreekLetters;
writeGreekLetter(greekLetter2);
```

This code will then correctly fail to compile:

```
Error: uncaught CTFE exception std.conv.ConvException("Value (2) does not match any member value of enum 'GreekLetters'"c)
```

Comment: CTFE can only be used, if the value is known at compile time, otherwise the program will not compile. But that's not the biggest issue: what I don't understand (hence my 2nd question) is why is it allowed in the first place. It would be very easy to say, that even though `cast` is a low-level operator, it is forbidden to use it to cast to an `enum` type. And the reason behind it, is that I cannot think of any use case, that cannot possibly be solved in another way than casting.

Comment: Moreover, this is not really an answer to my 1st question: as a library implementer, what should be the best practice then? I cannot rely on other developers, that they will use everything the standard library provides approprietly, so I have to assume, they will use `cast` mostly because they **can**. I understand, that the user acknowledges that s/he avoiding the type system, but that should not be effecting me, right?

Comment: You need to understand something: D is a **system programming language**! If the user really wanted to, they could do anything starting from using pointer arithmetics to access your private fields, to overwriting your functions' machine code with their own. As a library author, you have no power to force anything onto the user - merely guide them towards best practices using the language's tools. Casting is a way for the programmer to override these best practices if they decide they need to.

Comment: The recommended best practices for you as a library author: 1. Design your library so that it works correctly if it is used correctly. 2. Let the program crash with ugly errors if you detect that the code has been used incorrectly (indicating a bug in the program). Asserts, invariants and contracts are good tools for this. 3. If a value comes from user input (a file or network), always validate it using `enforce` and exceptions.

Comment: So, to answer the two questions in your question above: 1. No - unless the value of the `enum` is coming from a file or network, a `final switch` is appropriate there and your code is good as it is. 2. Because casting to `enum`s is often useful in practice, e.g. if the integral value is read as an `int` from a file.

Comment: In some cases a number might be a valid value for enums even if the member isn't specified. In that case the casting is the correct way though. - To answer your first comment @PeterVaro This is common with things like bitfields in enums etc.